# How could I migrate my database with "php artisan migrate" in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I clone my project from gitlab and I make it on my new computer.
But I get nothing ouput after I run `php artisan migrate` and the corresponding table is not created.

Output of `php artisan migrate:status` below.
[image]

What the meaning of "Ran?" and why status my migration file are all "N". `php artisan migrate` will create these tables successfully only when the "Ran?"s are "Y"?

Comment: After running `php artisan migrate`, check your Laravel log (typically in `storage/logs/laravel.log`). Consider putting some `Log::info()` statements at the top of each migration as well to see if they're running at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Y in the Ran column means the migration has been done.

Check your .ENV file , make sure your database settings are correct, also make sure you actually created the database beforehand.

Comment: I'm sure that my database settings in .env file are correct and I really created the database. I've tried `php artisan migrate` many times but I have no tables created yet.

Comment: try running     php artisan migrate -v     and post the output here

Comment: Well, I think I know the cause that the privilege of mysql account is wrong. Thanks for you comment

Answer (score 0):

clear the entire laravel cache to stay up to date with current .env settings, it might help.

Answer (score -1):

try using `php artisan migrate:refresh` sometime it happens with  me and i find out it's already migrated

Comment: Uh, it'd be really worth noting that `migrate:refresh` will DELETE any existing database contents.

Comment: i it will delete all the data but it will make the migration fine and u can extract the data while u process the migration and import it again